# Cucumber: while execute first script "WARNING: No features found at classpath:/Runner" is displaying

Tags: java, cucumber, maven-plugin

Cucumber :While Execute my first script in cucmber am getting  "WARNING: No features found at classpath:/Runner" .
Please refer the jar file details in the attached snap.
My first test case is:
Feature: To verify Boats Application login
Scenario: Verification of user credetials
Given Open the chrome Browser and check the application
When Enter the Username and Password
Then Verify the login success
And Verify Homepage title

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>cucumberwithselenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumberwithselenium</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>cucumberwithselenium</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0</version>
    </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

      </dependencies>


    </project>
```

[Cucumber error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFUUh.jpg)

Comment: Try to put your files under src/test/java instead of src/main/java

Comment: You shouldn't use the "code snippet" tool for non-javascript/html code. Use the "Code sample" tool or three backticks (```) instead.

Comment: You're mixing two versions of Cucumber. Make sure you're only using one version first. Follow the tutorial https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/